# Where to place regular Controllers and ApiControllers

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have been looking into MVC4 WebApi examples recently. Those sample applications are very simple, containing only a few pages. Since their purpose is just to show how to use ApiController, the application is kept at minimum in structure.

In a larger web applications, there will be many regular controllers and Api controllers. How are we supposed to arrange them in an organized way? Is it a good practice to place all api controllers into one folder and `$.ajax()` on each view calls from there? Or, is it better to put the api controller along with the regular controller which renders the views where the related `$.ajax()` is located?

What is the suggested practice?

*Some thoughts added here:*

I am going to spend more time thinking it over. Now my plan is that the Standard Controller will only be used to render Views. No view models will be passed through the standard controllers. That is, no `return View(model)`. The views will be populated with json objects returned from API Controllers using client-side programming like jQuery templates. [Am I too extreme in this? No `return View(model)`? Really?]

If this is okay, then the regular controllers will not call any worker services. Instead, all worker services should be called from API controllers. Then, how am I supposed to place those WorkerServices and their Interfaces?

What's more, what if I want to have areas? Should I place API and WorkerServices outside areas? or have an API folder and a WorkerServices folder for each area?

I will definitely think it over and over this afternoon to make a calculated decision. Please let me know your suggestions or experiences. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could branch your `Controllers` folder to keep a separation between your Api controllers and your standard controllers:

```
              |--- Api
Controllers - |
              |--- Standard
```

Or the following separation:

```
|-- Controllers
|-- Api
```

It's really a matter of personal taste. I would just watch out to not mix standard and Api controllers in the same folder as they are more difficult to distinguish.

As far as the `$.ajax` calls are concerned, it doesn't really matter where the controllers are located and how are they organized on the server. It's up to the routing engine to dispatch an incoming url to the corresponding controller.

Comment: Thank you. And especially thanks for the figures. Those are exactly what I was trying to describe.